# How to calculate this limit with x to 0?

Tags: limits

Can anyone help with a step-by-step on how to calculate this limit, please?

$$ \lim_{x\to 0} \left(\frac{\cos x+\ln(1+x)}{x\sin x}\right)$$

Comment: Just set $x=0$ to find $$\dfrac10$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting $x=0$ in the expression gives $\frac{1}{0} = \infty$ directly but I would check $\lim_{x \to 0^-}$ and $\lim_{x \to 0^+}$ in order to be sure the limit exists:
$$\lim_{x \to 0^-}\left(\frac{\cos x+\ln(1+x)}{x\sin x}\right) = \frac{1+0}{(0^-)\cdot(0^-)} = +\infty$$

$$\lim_{x \to 0^+}\left(\frac{\cos x+\ln(1+x)}{x\sin x}\right) = \frac{1+0}{(0^+)\cdot(0^+)} = +\infty$$

Therefore, 
$$\lim_{x \to 0}\left(\frac{\cos x+\ln(1+x)}{x\sin x}\right) = +\infty$$

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{\cos x+\ln(1+x)}{x\sin x}=\frac{1}{x^2}\frac{\cos x+\ln(1+x)}{\frac{\sin x}{x}}\to +\infty\cdot1=+\infty$$

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an indeterminate form : the numerator tends to $1$ as $x$ tends to $0$, and $\:x\sin x\sim_0 x^2$, so the expression is equivalent to $\dfrac1{x^2}$, which tends to $+\infty$.