# Same limit, but now x to π/2?

Tags: limits

Can anyone help with a step-by-step on how to calculate this limit, please?

$$ \lim_{x\to π/2} \left(\frac{\cos x+\ln(1+x)}{x\sin x}\right)$$

I got some really interesting answers earlier when we let x to 0:

[How to calculate this limit with x to 0?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2587511/how-to-calculate-this-limit-with-x-to-0/2587525)

Comment: The function is continuous at that value. Just plug in $\dfrac{\pi}{2}$.

Comment: Isn’t your function continuous and defined at $\frac{\pi}{2}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have no problem. Just directly substitute $x = \frac{\pi}{2}$. $$\lim_{x \to \frac{\pi}{2}} \, f(x) = \frac{\cos \frac{\pi}{2}+\ln(2+ \pi) - \ln 2}{\frac{\pi}{2}}= \, ?$$

Answer (score 1):

The denominator does not vanish at $\frac \pi 2$, so your function is defined and continuous there (because it is built by the addition, division and composition of continuous functions), so you may “plug in” the value. No tricks involved other than exploiting continuity.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the funtion is contiunuos at $x=\frac{\pi}{2}$, thus:

$$\frac{\cos x+\ln(1+x)}{x\sin x}\to\frac{0+\ln(1+\frac{\pi}{2})}{\frac{\pi}{2}\cdot 1}=\frac{2}{\pi}\ln(1+\frac{\pi}{2})$$